# Cannot specify name and version when generating a lock file

Tags: conan

I am using a simple conan file example from a [repository of examples](https://github.com/conan-io/examples/tree/master/libraries/folly/basic). I would like to generate a lockfile, but when I try the command, I get this error:

```
.../folly/basic $ conan lock create
ERROR: Specify the 'name' and the 'version'
```

When I try to do so, following [the documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/lock.html), I still get the same error:

```
.../folly/basic $ conan lock create --name=libb --version=0.2
ERROR: Specify the 'name' and the 'version'

.../folly/basic $ conan lock create --name libb --version 0.2
ERROR: Specify the 'name' and the 'version'
```

Does anybody have any advice? I am sure it's something obvious, but I am new to conan.

Comment: Can you please clarify what this has to do with `C`?

Comment: Well. Conan is a package manager used when building C and C++ programs, so one may expect to find developers that are familiar with this tool and had a similar issue. The same way you would tag a maven issue with "java".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conan [lock create](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/lock.html#conan-lock-create) requires a `conanfile.py` file which is not present in your example. That example uses a simple `conanfile.txt` to install the project dependencies (Folly and OpenSSL).

You still can generate the lock file by installing those requirements:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build/
$ conan install ..
...
$ ls
conan.lock  conanbuildinfo.cmake  conanbuildinfo.txt  conaninfo.txt  graph_info.json
```

Also, note that you are not passing the conanfile path, as required by the command:

```
.../folly/basic $ conan lock create
ERROR: Specify the 'name' and the 'version'
```

Instead, you should pass the path where the `conanfile.py` is installed:

```
$ conan lock create conanfile.py
```

However, if you want to generate a lock file only for a single reference (e.g. Folly), you can directly do it by the follow command:

```
$ conan lock create --reference folly/2020.08.10.00@  -r conancenter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just for my understanding. there's no way to generate a lockfile given a conanfile.txt? I am asking because the doc talks about a "conanfile", not specifically about a .py version of it.

Comment: Correct, it should be a folder where a conanfile.py should exist, or a conanfile.py path. There is a question made some time ago which is related to this point: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/7557 In summary, Conan 2.0 should be more explicit to avoid doubts when executing a command.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, as I have now a conanfile.py in the folder and if I run "conan lock create ." it does not work, while I definitely have a conanfile.py in the folder. The error says "ERROR: Path argument must include filename like 'conanfile.py' or 'path/conanfile.py'". A "conan install ." will instead work, but I would like to generate the lock without installing the packages.

Comment: sample code here:
https://github.com/bbossola/sample-conanfile-py

Comment: try `conan lock create conanfile.py` then

Comment: Yep, that works. I will probably stop reading the docs :)

Comment: Also, if this is the correct syntax, it'd be helpful to update your answer